# Heroku Automatic Certificate Management - Domains Failing Validation

Tags: django, heroku

I'm trying to use the new Heroku Automated Certificate Management.

when i run `heroku certs:auto`

I get the following error:

`Some domains are failing validation, please verify that your DNS matches: heroku domains`

I can't figure out what the problem is and have followed this document from Heroku https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management#troubleshooting

I have my DNS on godaddy setup as follows:

[image]

and when i run `heroku domains`

i get this

[image]

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: ok...it was a pretty easy fix...i was missing the .com in my domain name..woops

Comment: Where actually were you missing the .com?