# Heroku Automated Certificate Management failed with one domain

Tags: ssl, heroku, ssl-certificate, namecheap, dnsimple

I am trying to get the SSL certification for my app with Heroku, but the [Automated Certificate Management](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management) is failing for one of both domain names.

I created the dyno before March 2017, so I had to run `heroku certs:auto:enable` as explained [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management).

Then, `heroku domains` returns:

```
Domain Name         DNS Record Type  DNS Target
───────────────     ───────────────  ─────────────────────────────
example.com         ALIAS or ANAME   example.com.herokudns.com
www.example.com     CNAME            www.example.com.herokudns.com
```

This seems to be in line with [what heroku expects](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/understanding-ssl-on-heroku#dns-targets-for-acm).

Anyway, `heroku certs:auto` returns:

```
Domain             Status
───────────────    ────────────
example.com        Failing
www.example.com    OK
```

I admit that I am quite illiterate for settings concerning domains, DNS and so on. Therefore, this might be a very simple mistake from my side. However, I read the [Heroku troubleshooting documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management#troubleshooting) and also similar questions in SO such as a [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43026271) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49578145) and still have no clue what is wrong.

The fact that `www.example.com` is OK but `example.com` is failing just confuses me even more. And unfortunately, I received a notification email with no [failure reason](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management#failure-reasons).

### Namecheap

I guess the problem is either on Heroku or where I bought the domain. That is Namecheap.com.

There, at the `Domain` tab I have:

`NAMESERVERS       Namecheap BasicDNS`

```
REDIRECT DOMAIN   Source URL     Destination
                  example.com    http://www.example.com
```

And at the `Advanced DNS` tab:

```
Type                  Host    Value                               TTL
-------------         -----   -------------------------------     -------
CNAME Record          www     example.com.herokudns.com           Automatic
TXT Record            @       google-site-verification...         Automatic
URL Redirect Record   @       http://www.example.com/ Unmasked
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

### Update

The issue seems to be due to Namecheap. I found the [following ticket](https://help.heroku.com/NH44MODG/my-root-domain-isn-t-working-what-s-wrong) on Heroku:

> ### Issue
>
> User is having trouble pointing their root domain (aka apex
>   domain/naked domain) to their Heroku app, either with setting the
>   right DNS records, or accessing it over HTTPS.
>
> ### Resolution
>
> Root domains on Heroku require the use of "CNAME-like" records, often
>   referred to as ALIAS or ANAME records.
>
> Unfortunately, a number of popular DNS hosts such as GoDaddy,
>   Namecheap, Bluehost, and others do not support these types of records.
>   Instead they tend to offer the following:
>
> - A records
> - URL redirects / forwarding
>
> There are caveats with both of these options...

Surprisingly, I did not find any place where all the steps were explained clearly. What I did so far is:

1. Open an account with a DNS host that supports this. I took DNSimple. At the time of writing, prices start from 5€/month but there is a trial month for free.
2. Transfering the domain costs 14€/year, so I just [pointed the name servers at Namecheap to DNSimple](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/delegating-dnsimple-hosted/) and added the domain to DNSimple to create the DNS records.
3. Then came the configuration on DNSimple. I followed the step 1 in the documentation to [redirect HTTP to HTTPs](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/redirect-heroku/#redirect-https); ignored the step 2, since Heroku's ACM had already done it; and for the step 3 the article [Pointing the Domain Apex to Heroku](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/domain-apex-heroku/) was very helpful. I added manually an `ALIAS record` and I also added a `CNAME` record, like this:

   ```
   Type        Name                   Content
   ─────       ───────────────        ───────────────────────
   ALIAS       example.commyapp.com.herokudns.com
   CNAME       www.example.commyapp.com.herokudns.com
   ```

At the beginning nothing was working and the browser showed the following error:

> ### This site can’t be reached
>
> www.example.com’s server IP address could not be found.

Checking the [troubleshotting documentation](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/domain-resolution-issues/) I saw that the only possibility was the `Name server propagation delay`, so I waited. It felt like a very long time, but it actually took less than one hour until the site got online again.

However, the SSL certification keeps failing more than 48 hours later...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For future reference: after contacting Heroku support, they manually refreshed my certificate request and it was finally issued for my app...

Answer (score 4):

Check the answer here especially the CloudFlare solution as it is free

> Automated certificate management also provisions you a free SSL cert
>   from https everywhere. You don’t need to buy a cert.
>
> However namecheap won’t work with ACM because they don’t allow an
>   “alias” record for your “apex” domain I.e. your domain with no
>   subdomain so https://example.com not https://www.example.com
>
> Your options are switch to a dns registrar that supports an “alias”
>   record such as dnsimple. They charge $5 a month in addition to the
>   domain registration fee.
>
> Or alternatively use a free cloudflare instance which comes with SSL.
>
> If you already bought a cert there is a way to upload it to Heroku via
>   an SSL addon.
>
> I use both DNSimple/Heroku ACM on some apps and cloudflare on some
>   others. Both are equally nice but cloudflare is free and gives you a
>   CDN too.

https://www.reddit.com/r/Heroku/comments/7wh5r4/setting_up_ssl_with_heroku_namecheap/